# How to change the location of div in responsive?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have three divs as described in the image...i want to change the location of divs as they go responsive...

Is it possible to do so? and how?

[image]

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 text-center "><h3 class="border">Div-1</h3></div>
           <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 text-center "><h3 class="border">Div-2</h3></div>
           <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 text-center "><h3 class="border">Div-3</h3></div>
       </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**By using the Bootstrap defaults** you would like to push and pull columns by simply adding some additional classes to them.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 text-center"><h3 class="border">Div-1</h3></div>
       <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-sm-push-4 text-center"><h3 class="border">Div-3</h3></div>
       <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-pull-4 text-center"><h3 class="border">Div-2</h3></div>
   </div>
```

The point is to move the **3rd col** to swap places with the **2nd col**, since the 2nd will be at the bottom when it goes down to mobile. Using `.col-sm-pull` and `.col-sm-push` will grant you the ability to move columns around easily without breaking anything with unnecessary float styling or anything else.

Refer to [Bootstrap's official guide to column ordering](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering).

Comment: Though your break-points are unusual, you might wanna adjust the default settings for these CSS attributes or overwrite them if this is a common break-point for your website.

Comment: The concept helped me but the answer is here                                 `<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 text-center">
                <h3 class="border">Div-1</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-sm-push-4 text-center">
                <h3 class="border">Div-3</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-pull-4 text-center">
                <h3 class="border">Div-2</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> `

Comment: Yes, breakpoints and column order in general is up to your preference, glad to see you got it figured out! :) Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
       <div class="row">
           <div class="first col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 text-center "><h3 class="border">Div-1</h3></div>
           <div class="second col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 text-center "><h3 class="border">Div-2</h3></div>
           <div class="third col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 text-center "><h3 class="border">Div-3</h3></div>
       </div>
   </div>



    @media only screen and (max-width:990px) and (min-width:320px){
         .first, .third{
           float:left;
           width:48%; 
        }
        .second {
          width:100%;
          float:right;
           display:block;
          clear:both;
        }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works,

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 text-center "><h3 class="border">Div-1</h3></div>
           <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 text-center "><h3 class="border">Div-2</h3></div>
           <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4 text-center "><h3 class="border">Div-3</h3></div>
       </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp if your element hasn´t any unique id or class.
and

```
float: right;
```

As long as

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 990px) and (min-width:320px)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
           <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 text-center">
            <h3 class="border">Div-1</h3>
           </div>
           <div class="hidden-sm hidden-xs col-md-4 col-lg-4 text-center">
            <h3 class="border">Div-2</h3>
           </div>
           <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 text-center">
            <h3 class="border">Div-3</h3>
           </div>
           <div class="hidden-lg hidden-md col-xs-12 col-sm-12 visible-sm-block visible-xs-block text-center">
            <h3 class="border">Div-2</h3>
           </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Comment: This would cause the developer to fill in the same content twice, not ideal.

Comment: But this is much useful expect add more code to your css file.

Comment: You can use bootstrap's default CSS classes to make columns swap places, so no need for extra CSS code.